# How to get the text with in span tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get text within this span tag using its class:

```
<span id="prizevalue_g12" class="pull-right grid_val">£12</span>
```

I want to get `12`. I tried the below code:

```
var ex_price = $(".grid_val").html();
```

and

```
ex_price = $(".grid_val").html();
```

Comment: What you have should work fine (although `text()` would arguably be better in this case), you just need to remove the `£` symbol from the result - `replace('£', '')`

Comment: you can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: an answer would be useful for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace()` to remove £.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ex_price = $(".grid_val").html();
  ex_price = $(".grid_val").html();  
  var ans=ex_price.replace('£', '') ;
  alert(ans); 
});
```

This is just a tought, but I think this would be a perfect place to use some custom data-attributes, like data-value. It would work nice especially if you have a lot of these values to get.

The outcome would be smthn like this:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<span class="grid_val" data-value="12">£12</span>
<span class="grid_val" data-value="15">£15</span>
<span class="grid_val" data-value="13">£13</span>
<span class="grid_val" data-value="1">£1</span>

<script>
$(".grid_val").each(function(){
  var value = $(this).attr("data-value");
  //do something with it
});
</script>
```